# Почему нужны копии при инициализации std::vector с помощью std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, вектор, инициализация

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    S() = default;
    S(const S&) = delete;
};

struct A {
  A(std::initializer_list<std::unique_ptr<S>>);
} a{std::make_unique<S>()};           // 1

std::vector v{std::make_unique<S>()}; // 2
```

Почему я могу сделать 1, но не могу 2? Читал, что это из-за того, что *initializer list* создаёт копии, т.к. не может сделать *move* из *const T* массива. Но ведь тогда и первый пример бы не работал.

Comment: В первом примере с содержимым `initializer_list` ничего не происходит. Если будите пытаться его копировать - получите ту же проблему, что и во втором случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но ведь тогда и первый пример бы не работал.

А там нет попытки move **из** константного массива. Константность массива не мешает перемещать **в** него. (Но в вашем случае даже перемещения не происходит, элемент создается сразу в массиве благодаря [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).)

Есть маленькая библиотечка [`better_braces`](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces), которая это обходит: <kbd>[запустить](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/better_braces/master/include/better_braces.hpp%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Astruct+S+%7B%0A++++S()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++S(const+S%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astd::vector%3Cstd::unique_ptr%3CS%3E%3E+v+%3D+init%7Bstd::make_unique%3CS%3E()%7D%3B%0A//++++++++++++++%5E%7E%7E%7E%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.6226993728496,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%270%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:31.394545063431934,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:48.95267217704424,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <better_braces.hpp>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    S() = default;
    S(const S&) = delete;
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<S>> v = init{std::make_unique<S>()};
//                                  ^~~~
```

(Я автор.)

Comment: @Nikita Ну да. По той же причине, по которой `const S arr[] = {S{}, S{}, S{}};` работает. Чтобы создать временный массив, не обязательно делать копирование/перемещение. Они нужны только чтобы потом скопировать из него элементы куда-то еще.

Comment: @Nikita Хорошо заметили. Да, получается, там вообще нет move.